# Sql - use (Group by) with 2 columns

Tags: sql, group-by

I have table named (TB1) with columns (Device - Order_id - qty) ....
[image]

I want write sql query to show each (order No) with (device name) with (total device qty) in this order  ... I know we must use (group by) ... But I don't know how do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by two columns like this : `group by col1, col2`.
So your query should be something like:

```
select Device, Order_no, sum(Qty)
from table_name
group by Device, Order_no
```

Comment: update : thanks a lot everything is working 100%

Comment: @PHPbeginner no problem buddy, have a nice day ^^

Comment: Al-salam Alaikum brother ... Do you coding in PHP & SQL ... I need some codes in PHP